# Matching multiple objects in a MOCK_METHOD

Tags: c++, unit-testing, mocking, googletest, googlemock

I am trying to mock a method `Handler::Foo` to throw an exception that takes in two objects as parameters i.e `SomeStruct`, `SomeClass`. The former is created `Source::Bar` on the fly whereas `SomeClass` is passed from main.

I used MATCHER but it returns a single object which doesn't match with what `Foo` expects (2 parameters), hence the error.

> no matching function for call to 'MockHandler::gmock_Foo(MatchMatcherP2<SomeStruct, SomeClass>)'

```
ACTION(MyThrowException)    
{
  throw std::invalid_argument("Some exception thrown!");
}

TEST(UtClass, TestSourceBar)
{
    auto mockHandler = std::make_shared<MockHandler>();
    SomeStruct someStruct = {.a = 10};
    SomeClass someClass;

    EXPECT_CALL(*mockHandler, Foo(Match(someStruct, someClass)))
                .Times(1)
                .WillRepeatedly(MyThrowException()); // ERROR
}
```

Is there a way to mock `Handler::Foo` such that it throws an exception?

[Here's a live sample](https://godbolt.org/z/vhTr3j6q7)

```
struct SomeStruct 
{
    int a;
};

class SomeClass 
{
    public:
    // some methods...
};

class Handler
{
    public:
    virtual void Foo(const SomeStruct&, SomeClass)
    {
        // stuff...
    }
};

class Source
{
    std::weak_ptr<Handler> _handler;

    public:
    Source(std::weak_ptr<Handler> handler) : _handler(handler) {}

    void Bar(SomeClass someClass)
    { 
        SomeStruct s = {.a = 10};        
        if (auto sp = _handler.lock())
        {
            sp->Foo(s, someClass);   // simulate this call
        }
    }
};

class MockHandler : public Handler
{
    public:
    MOCK_METHOD(void, Foo, (const SomeStruct&, SomeClass), (override));
};

MATCHER_P2(Match, someStruct, someClass, "")
{
    return arg.a == someStruct.a && arg.someClass == someClass;
}

ACTION(MyThrowException)    
{
  throw std::invalid_argument("Some exception thrown!");
}
  
TEST(UtClass, TestSourceBar)
{
    auto mockHandler = std::make_shared<MockHandler>();
    SomeStruct someStruct = {.a = 10};
    SomeClass someClass;

    EXPECT_CALL(*mockHandler, Foo(Match(someStruct, someClass)))
                .Times(1)
                .WillRepeatedly(MyThrowException()); // ERROR

    
    Source source(mockHandler);
    source.Bar(someClass); // should throw an exception...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matcher is meant to test some conditions for a single argument, so you would need to use a separate matcher for each one.

It's not really clear what you want to test here, but one way of doing what your example shows would be:

```
class SomeClass 
{
    public:
    bool operator==(const SomeClass &) const = default;
    // some methods...
};

MATCHER_P(MatchSomeStruct, someStruct, "")
{
    return arg.a == someStruct.a;
}

MATCHER_P(MatchSomeClass, someClass, "")
{
    return arg == someClass;
}
  
TEST(UtClass, TestSourceBar)
{
    auto mockHandler = std::make_shared<MockHandler>();
    SomeStruct someStruct = {.a = 10};
    SomeClass someClass;

    EXPECT_CALL(*mockHandler, Foo(MatchSomeStruct(someStruct), MatchSomeClass(someClass)))
                .Times(1)
                .WillRepeatedly(MyThrowException());
```

This will of course check the two parameters separately. If you need to check the two parameters as a whole then you could look into adding a [`With()`](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/docs/gmock_cook_book.md#matching-multiple-arguments-as-a-whole) clause.

Comment: that does make sense but what you have there would still error out. If you do `return &arg == &someClass` however, it builds fine at least but the `EXPECT_CALL` itself fails. https://godbolt.org/z/vrKbd7bTE <- you can see what I am trying to achieve by checking the caller code where I invoke `source.Bar(someClass);`

Comment: You would probably need to define an equality(==) operator for SomeClass to get that comparison to work.

Comment: Can you please edit your response cause that doesn't answer the question, in fact it doesn't even compile

Comment: OK, I added the equality operator as I suggested earlier. You are passing the class instance by value, so checking the address of it is of course going to fail. You need to add an == operator so in order to do comparison by value. I still don't quite understand what the purpose of the exception throwing is, so I'm just trying to help with your question about how to work with matchers.

Comment: Thanks. That did the trick! I have another similar code that I'm having trouble with. Can I ask you here?

Comment: You're welcome, glad to know it helped. You should make a new question, and then leave a link to it here if you like.

Comment: Thanks Chris. This is the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74586965/call-to-implicitly-deleted-copy-constructor-of-a-mock-class?noredirect=1#comment131662358_74586965