# How to get around not passing a copyable object to the MATCHER within MOCK_METHOD?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

I am attempting at having a `MOCK_METHOD` `BarClass::Bar` throw an exception however I seem to be running into a following error

> error: call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'FooMock'

And it's probably happening at the `==` inside `MATCHER_P`.

It seems as though `MOCK_METHOD` creates a data member that's not copyable however that leaves me with an option to use a pointer, which I can't really use since `BarClass::Bar` takes `fooMock` as a reference.

Is there a way to pass a dereferenced object to `Matcher`?

```
class FooClass
{
    public:
    virtual void Foo() const{}
};

class FooMock : public FooClass
{
    public:
    MOCK_METHOD(void, Foo, (), (const override));
};

struct BarClass
{
    void Bar(const FooMock& fooMock) {}
};

class BarMock : public BarClass
{
    public:
    MOCK_METHOD(void, Bar, (FooMock& fooMock), (const override));
};

MATCHER_P(Matcher, fooMock, "")
{
    return arg == fooMock;
}

ACTION(MyThrowException)    
{
  throw std::invalid_argument("Some exception thrown!");
}

TEST(UtClass, Test)
{
    auto fooMock = std::make_shared<FooMock>();
    BarMock barMock;
    
    EXPECT_CALL(barMock, Bar (Matcher(*fooMock))) // <-- problem here
            .Times(1)
            .WillRepeatedly(MyThrowException());

    barMock.Bar(*fooMock);       // should throw
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/rEGzxjoaY

Comment: `<source>:19:5: note: copy constructor of 'FooMock' is implicitly deleted because field 'gmock10_Foo_19' has a deleted copy constructor` due to `MOCK_METHOD(void, Foo, (), (const override));`

Comment: but why though? Why does having a `MOCK_METHOD` resulting in deleting an implicit ctor?

Comment: If a member variable doesn't have a copy constructor, the containing class can't synthesize a copy constructor.

Comment: the question was more like why the implicit copy ctor was deleted though. Is it because of `MOCK_METHOD`?

Comment: Presumably.  You'd have to check to see what `MOCK_METHOD` expands to.

Comment: So how's this question a duplicate? it's used within the context of gmock

Comment: You'd have to ask the person who closed it.  I suppose it is because the other Q&A answers why copy constructors are not implicitly generated by the compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arguments to matchers are passed by copy per default. This is somewhat documented [here](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/docs/reference/matchers.md#generic-comparison). You can fix this by wrapping your argument in `std::ref()` or better `std::cref()` so you can't accidentally modify it:

```
    EXPECT_CALL(barMock, Bar (Matcher(std::cref(*fooMock))))
            .Times(1)
            .WillRepeatedly(MyThrowException());
```

https://godbolt.org/z/1r695brK4

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I see you added a 'dummy' assignment operator as well. That really is required, eh?

Comment: That is not an assignment operator, but a comparison operator. That is only required because you do a `==` comparison on FooMock.